# Spark read avro results from a previous write results in "Not an avro data file" due to _SUCCESS file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I'm using the great databricks connector to read/write avro files.
I have the following code

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).avro(someDirectory)
```

Problem is that when I try to read this directory using 
    sqlContext.read.avro(someDirectory)

it fails with

```
java.io.IOException: Not an Avro data file
```

due to the existence of the _SUCCESS file in that directory.

setting `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")` solves the issue but I rather avoid doing it.

This sounds like a quite generic problem so I may be doing something wrong?

Comment: Ehm, why would you _"rather avoid"_ setting the configuration that solves the problem? The thing is, Spark creates the `_SUCCESS` file by default (and many users are very happy with this), so when you have a specific scenario where you do not want the file, it seems only fair to me that _you_ have to set the configuration to disable it.

Comment: just because it's sounds like a hack to solve a more common problem.

Comment: But it is not necessarily a _"common problem"_. Some people prefer it and some people don't - which is why the configuration option is nice :)

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that it's not a matter of preference, because leaving the file simply won't work - anyone who reads / writes avro files must have this setting, which sounds a bit odd.